# How to Test JSON POST Request in Play?

Tags: json, playframework-2.0, postman

How can I test the POST & UPDATE API that I create in Play?

This is the Routes.

```
GET         /api/v1/users               controllers.UserController.list()
POST        /api/v1/users               controllers.UserController.create()
GET         /api/v1/users/:id           controllers.UserController.get(id: Long)
PATCH       /api/v1/users/:id           controllers.UserController.update(id: Long)
DELETE      /api/v1/users/:id           controllers.UserController.delete(id: Long)
```

I tried to use the Postman Chrome extension to make a POST request. I choose Raw & set the type to JSON.

However, when it is read in the action, the request body is as follow:

```
DefaultRequestBody(None,None,Some({"name":"rrr","email":"ABCD","password":"PASS"}),None,None,None,false)
```

Referring to this doc (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.1/api/scala/index.html#play.core.j.JavaParsers$$DefaultRequestBody), the JSON is supposed to be in the 4th parameter.
This cased an error when I call :

```
User newUser = Json.fromJson(request().body().asJson(), User.class);
```

How can I fix this?.